# Archivo .cpp se encuentra en cmd, pero no en vscode

Tags: c++, vscode, gcc

El fallo parece ser de principiante pero no se por qué pasa.

Tengo un archivo .cpp en un directorio y necesito compilarlo.

Esto se supone que lo hace automáticamente VSCode con `tasks.json` el cual muestro a continuación:

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Al ejecutar esta tarea, me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
> Executing task: C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo <

Iniciando la compilación...
g++ "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\OneDrive\Escritorio\LOC -- OIE\Second_Week\EjercicioA.cpp" -o "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\OneDrive\Escritorio\LOC -- OIE\Second_Week\EjercicioA.exe"
g++: error: "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\OneDrive\Escritorio\LOC -- OIE\Second_Week\EjercicioA.cpp": No such file or directory

g++: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.

La compilación ha finalizado con errores.

Las tareas reutilizarán el terminal, presione cualquier tecla para cerrarlo.
```

Me da un error como que no existe el directorio, en cambio, si **COPIO Y PEGO LITERALMENTE** el directorio que intenta acceder el archivo exe se crea sin problemas, es decir, ejecutar esto:

````
g++ "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\OneDrive\Escritorio\LOC -- OIE\Second_Week\EjercicioA.cpp" -o "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\OneDrive\Escritorio\LOC -- OIE\Second_Week\EjercicioA.exe"```
````

Comment: Esas rutas con espacios y caracteres especiales tienen una cara de causar problemas...

Comment: ¿Has intentado compilar en VSCode pero desde un directorio que no tenga caracteres especiales ni espacios en el nombre?

Comment: Trata de cambiar tu URI a este formato `"C://Users//Esteban Sánchez//OneDrive//..."`

Comment: No puedo cabiar la URI porque es la predeterminada de VSCode. @EduardoJiménez ten en cuenta que la direccion del archivo la crea VSCode en la task